# Cannot locate "com.android.support:"

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to import a SDK into android studio. The SDK is called sdk & demo. After much time spent on google I found out that the SDK has to be compatible with the Project created. So I have amended certain things like the `compileSdkVersion 29` for the sdk & demo SDK amongst other changes. However I saw that the `com.android.support:` also needs to be the same versions.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

However, as shown in the first code snippet (build.gradle (:app)), shown above there is no `com.android.support:`. Hence I cannot alter the version of the build.gradle(:sdk & demo) for the sdk & demo `com.android.support:`. Therefore the build.gradle is producing an error. Why does not build.gradle (:app), shown first, doesn't have the `com.android.support:` and how do I "install" it? Not sure if the install is the right term here.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation(name: 'lib_ui-release', ext: 'aar')
implementation(name:'blebase-release', ext:'aar')
implementation(name:'pulltorefreshlayout-release', ext:'aar')
//implementation project(path: ':blebase')
 }
```

[image: Error Picture]

Comment: It is not clear when do you have the error "Cannot locate “com.android.support:”. At build time o runtime?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti at build time. The error is caused because the `build.gradle(:app)` does not have the `com.android.support:`. Please see pic added.

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to caused by the SDK & demo SDK being of the older versions of Android. Recently Android as now moved to androidX. To solve the issue just refractor the SDK to androidX.

The second option is to install a lower version of Android Studio.